# Continuous Testing Tool for IntelliJ 14

Tags: java, unit-tests

I'm using IntelliJ 14 and looking for a plugin / tool that will automatically run tests as and when they're updated.

I've looking into both Fireworks and Infiniti, neither of which seem to work with this version of the IDE. I cannot use the TeamCity Integration as funding doesn't allow.

Are there any other tools / methods that I could try?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Just to clarify; I don't want to run all tests on save, only the ones that I may have changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

infinitest seems to fit the bill, but it's a bit tricky to use.

Also, there is a youtrack entry for JetBrains to include continuous testing as a feature for the future versions - you might want to add your vote to the list:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6398